# Preprocessor macro check when defining a class's interface declaration

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a `NSWindowController` that has a window that I subclass in the xib. Up until 10.10 I had the window be a subclass (We will call it WindowSubclassB) which was a subclass of NSWindow and did some fancy UI stuff

Now with Yosemite, I no longer need to subclass my window on Yosemite, but I would still like to previous OS X versions.

I though of a few different options, such as just setting up a different .xib for Yosemite and other version, but my xib has a lot of pieces and that would mean that I would have to maintain two different xibs just to fix this.

So what I've attempted to do is use preprocessor macros to at build time determine which class to subclass

I tried:

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_10

@interface GFMOSXMainWindow : NSWindow

#else

@interface GFMOSXMainWindow : INAppStoreWindow

#endif
```

But the code does not get executed on Yosemite because it's not the MINIMUM requirement

What I would like to achieve is something like below:

```
#if CURRENT_OSX_VERSION == OSX_VERSION_10_10

@interface WindowSubclassA : NSWindow

#else

@interface WindowSubclassA : WindowSubclassB

#endif
```

I do not, however, see such a macro that at build time will tell me what the current version of OS X the app is built on is.

Also, if someone just knows how to tell a UIWindowController programmatically what class it's @property window should be initialized as, that would probably solve the whole issue :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just make your custom window subclass do nothing but pass through to super on platforms where it's not needed. If you're deploying to OSes prior to 10.10, where you still need/want the additional functionality, there's no getting around the need to compile that functionality into the app. And there aren't very good ways of conditionally modifying the superclass of the actual window class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do is in that, the code is not compiled multiple times for different system versions. If anything, it'd be compiled differently for different processors (like 32/64 bit on OSX, or armv7, armv7s and arm64 on ios).
So I think it's not possible to achieve this in that way.

I don't have a good idea for alternative solution yet, that isn't some wild dynamic method setting using objc runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`NSWindowController initWithWindow:` would do it, though you'd have to initialize the `NSWindow` yourself. Alternatively, you could override `loadWindow` and call `self.setWindow = <custom window>`.

I'm not sure that answers your original question, but it does answer your "also" question.